# Soft back button in Android using Webview

Tags: android, button, webview

I'm writing an Android program using Webview that can use the hard back key on the device, no problem with this.

But when the program goes "outside" and navigates through  HTML / Javascript pages inside the Webview "wrapper" it cannot handle properly an href="javascript:window.history.back();" button, because it does not go up one level, just goes back and forward the previous page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript.window.history.back() function is designed to move back one step in the browser history. It does not (even on android platforms) emulate a click of the device's back button.

I believe the WebView component intercepts a press of the device's back button to allow a user to navigate back though the history until the point that the WebView was created (i.e. the first page viewed).

These two functions are completely separate, defined in different languages and one cannot be used for the other. If you want to implement the functionality of the device's back button you will need to do this within the application code, not a web page (a call to onKeyPress() should do the trick).

Comment: I'm not talking about the device back button; it is working for me. What I want is to have the same functionality in the soft back buttons within the browser pages called by Webview; but here the javascript window.history.back() just stoped working. That is my problem.